# Spring JPA repository conditional overloaded joinColumn implementation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a section of my database here, simplified for the question:

```
Supplier
  company_id    int
  location      String

Warehouse
  warehouse_id  int
  location      String

Store
  store_id      int
  location      String

Shipment
  shipment_id      int
  origin_id        int
  destination_id   int
```

Objective: The system is used to record and track shipments between Suppliers and warehouses, warehouses and stores, and between stores.

So originally I planned to implement this by creating 3 tables each to store one type of shipment, but i realized i can abstract that by creating one table called shipment, since all the possible origins and destinations have the same length and type(int) of ids. I use shipment.type to identify if the origin is a supplier, warehouse or store, and vice versa with dest_type. My problem is how do I implement this in JPA entities? My current pseudocode for this goes like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SHIPMENT")
public class Shipment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "SHIPMENT_ID")
    private int shipmentId;

    @Column(name = "ORIGIN_TYPE")
    private int originType;

    @Column(name = "DESTINATION_TYPE")
    private int destination_id;

    if(origin_type==1){
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "ORIGIN_ID", nullable = false)
        private Supplier supplier;
    }
    else if(origin_type==2){
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "ORIGIN_ID", nullable = false)
        private Warehouse warehouse;
    }
    else if(origin_type==3){
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "ORIGIN_ID", nullable = false)
        private Store store;
    }
//same for destinations
}
```

I have no idea if this is even possible? And I have no idea what keywords to search for to do this because I'm self learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case can be handled by `Table per class` of `Inheritance Mapping`.

> The Table Per Class strategy maps each entity to its table which contains all the properties of the entity, including the ones inherited.

You need to make the `Supplier`, `Warehouse` and `Store` classes as a subclass of `Shipment`.And use `@Inhertance` annotation for your `Shipment` class as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SHIPMENT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Shipment implements Serializable
```

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance#table-per-class) is an example of that.

**Edited Anwer**

Actually, your case mostly fit with [Joined Table](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance#joined-table)

for that, you need to change the Inheritence type as
`@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`